# Android Realm Subclass Instance Methods

Tags: java, android, realm

I've been reading a lot about [Realm](https://realm.io/) and it seems like a very neat tool and I would love to give it a try; however, I've read in a few different places that the Android version doesn't support non-static methods for RealmObject subclasses.

This isn't exactly clear in [their documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#objects). This implies that non-static methods aren't supported, but in their [FAQ](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq) section, under *Why do I need to have getters and setters for all my fields?*, they use public, non-static methods.

Also, it makes perfectly clear in [this](https://medium.com/@rutvijshah/why-i-did-not-choose-realm-io-for-my-android-app-f44562af5fb0) article that:

> You will get compilation errors for using ANY other methods in the model class. Think about this for a moment ...
>
> Yeah.. you can not have toString(), Static methods, not even other behavior methods in your model classes.

So I am a little confused. I understand I can't have custom getters/setters; I don't like it, but it's not a deal breaker. But not being able to have any non-static instance methods is another story.

So which is it? Can I or can I not have non-static instance methods in my RealmObject subclasses?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you wil use real Object to share your info , and use CustomObject to handle your info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you cannot have custom getters and setters.

#### What is allowed :

- Only private instance fields.
- Only default getter and setter methods.
- Static fields, both public and private.
- Static methods.
- Implementing interfaces with no methods.

#### What is NOT allowed :

- Custom getters and setters
- Extends from a non RealmObject
- Override `toString()` on `equals()`
- Other custom non-static methods

But [they are working on it](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/908)

To be clear, RTFM :

> Be aware that the getters and setters will be overridden by the generated proxy class used in the back by RealmObjects, so any custom logic you add to the getters & setters will not actually be executed.
>   **Limitations**
>   Due to how the proxy classes override getters and setters in the model classes there are some restrictions to what is allowed in a model class.
>
> Due to how the proxy classes override getters and setters in the model
>   classes there are some restrictions to what is allowed in a model
>   class:
>
> ```
> Only private instance fields.
> Only default getter and setter methods.
> Static fields, both public and private.
> Static methods.
> Implementing interfaces with no methods.
> ```
>
> This means that it is currently not possible to extend anything else
>   than RealmObject or to override methods like toString() or equals().
>   Also it is only possible to implement interfaces.

[Source](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#objects)

Comment: I understand the no getters and setters part, but what about other public, private, or static instance methods? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: You are allowed to use static fields and methods: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#objects

Comment: @cohenadair as you didn't have read the manual, see my updated answer

Comment: I did read the manual, and no where does it say specifically you can't have other, non-static methods. Thanks for clearing it up, though. Unfortunately, this is a deal breaker for me at this time.

Comment: what you can do is an User object that wrap a RealmUser for example. For me I've just move stuff to static methods and to my UserService

Comment: It helps if you move your logic out of your entity classes. I honestly don't see how this is a dealbreaker, unless someone's been doing it wrong for multiple thousand years. You literally just have to make an external class that executes the same logic on its parameter. I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe that's okay for a lot of people, but I really don't like it.  I want my object's data and logic to be in the same class because that's what makes sense.  It seems silly to me to have an external class for for methods that should be in the class itself. It might just be more of an organizational thing for me, but it just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your **RealmObject** subclasses are supposed to be POJOs that store data.

So they can have private fields, public getters/setters, and static methods/classes/enums/interfaces. That's it.

If you want anything else, you should move it to another class that has a method which takes your `realmObject` as a parameter.